# Unable use a Temporal Plot Tool in GRASS GIS

Tags: python, grass-gis, matplotlib, plot

I installed GRASS GIS following the tutorial on the website for the Ubuntu 18.04 version. However, the [Temporal Plot Tool](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/g.gui.tplot.html) function is not working, and is giving an error related to python.

Below is the error that is giving in the tool.

```
Unable to start Temporal Plot Tool

Motivo: The Temporal Plot Tool needs the "Matplotlib" (python-matploltib) package to be installed. Cannot load backend 'WXAgg' which requires the 'wx' interactive framework, as 'gtk3' is currently running

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/grass78/gui/wxpython/tplot/frame.py", line 36, in <module>
matplolib.use('WXAgg')
File "/home/luiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 296, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/luiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 358, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/luiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_init_.py", line 1281 in use 
plt.switch_backend(name)
File "/home/luiz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 237, in switch_backend
newbackend, required_framework, current_framework))
ImportError:Cannot load backend 'WXAgg' which requires the 'wx' interactive framework, as 'gtk3' is currently running

During handling odf the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/grass78/gui/wxpython/lmgr/frame.py", line 1930, in OnTplotTool
from tplot.frame import TplotFrame
File "/usr/local/grass78/gui/wxpython/tplot/frame.py", line 45, in 
<module>
'(python-matplotlib) package to be installed. {0}').format(e))
ImportError: The Temporal Plot Tool needs the "matplotlib" (python-matplotlib) package to be installed Cannot load backend 'WXAgg' which requires the 'wx' interactive framework, as 'gtk3' is currently running
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu#Quick_instructions (we have numerous Ubuntu installations running and did not encounter this problem)

Comment: hello, thanks for replying. so, I followed the instructions line by line, and I had this problem.
I reinstalled the grass and again followed with the same error.

Comment: Please open a bugreport here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues . Also include besides the message above also the output of `g.version -rge` to know the detailed library versions. Thanks

Comment: ... if needed, I can do that for you. But please post the error as text, not as PNG (otherwise I cannot copy over the error message)

Comment: Hi markusN,  I did what you asked

Comment: ok, I created the report: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/489  please consider to "Suscribe" to the bug (there is a button for it on GitHub - it will require that you have/create a GitHub login). Then you can follow the answers there.

Comment: A suggestion already came in (see the ticket), pls try and let us know.

Comment: Santos, does it work now?

Comment: Hi MarKusN, it Worked!.. Very Thanks, helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per issue (https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/489#issuecomment-609455498) here the solution:

```
apt install python3-matplotlib
```

The installation of the matplot library solved the reported with the Temporal Plot Tool on Ubuntu.

Comment: FYI: On Fedora (maybe others), additionally `python-matplotlib-wx` must be installed.